Pac4j logout and destroy @SessionScoped?
I would need help regarding destroy a session.
I´m using Pac4j and Keycloak
In my shiro.ini I have this config regarding logout:
#### Session
sessionIdCookie=org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie
sessionIdCookie.httpOnly = true
sessionIdCookie.name = sid
sessionIdCookie.domain = localhost
sessionIdCookie.maxAge = 36000000
sessionIdCookie.secure = true
sessionIdCookie.sameSite = LAX

    sessionManager =org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
    sessionManager.sessionIdCookie =$sessionIdCookie
    sessionManager.sessionIdCookieEnabled =true
    securityManager.sessionManager= $sessionManager

# 3,600,000 milliseconds = 1 hour -> set to 10 hours
sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout= 36000000

    logoutFilter = org.pac4j.jee.filter.LogoutFilter
    logoutFilter.config = $config
    logoutFilter.localLogout = true
    logoutFilter.centralLogout = true
    logoutFilter.destroySession = true
    
    ## PAC4J Filter
    /oauth/callback = callbackFilter
    /oauth/logout = logoutFilter

I have a Bean which include a logout function:
public void logout() {

    LOGGER.info("START logout");

    try {
            
        Faces.redirect(FacesUtil.findApplicationUrl() + "/oauth/logout");

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
    }

    LOGGER.info("END logout");
}

The logout is working and I will redirect to the Keycloak Logout page:

This works and I´m not logged in anymore.
But what is not destroyed are my @SessionScoped beans ?
I have a simple Controller which use a @PostConstruct function.
This will called after the login process.
@SessionScoped

@Named
public class RegistrationController implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    LOGGER.info("START init");

    //....

    LOGGER.info("END init");
}

It´s called the first time. Afterwards I logged out and it´s not called anymore.
This seams for me this @SessionScoped bean is still active for this session.
How can I solve this?
I want to destroy ALL @SessionBean scopes. How is this possible?
I´ve added a simple SessionListener:
-> Function "sessionCreated" is called, but if I logout, the "sessionDestroyed" is not called.
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionListener.class);

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        LOGGER.info("Session created: ID = {}", se.getSession().getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        LOGGER.info("Session destroyed: ID = {}", se.getSession().getId());
    }
}

in web.xml:
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.myapp.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>

My version:
<pac4jVersion>5.7.7</pac4jVersion>
<bujiVersion>8.1.0</bujiVersion>
<jeePac4jVersion>7.1.0</jeePac4jVersion>

<dependency>
            <groupId>io.buji</groupId>
            <artifactId>buji-pac4j</artifactId>
            <version>${bujiVersion}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakartaee-pac4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jeePac4jVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pac4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${pac4jVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pac4j-cas</artifactId>
            <version>${pac4jVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pac4j-saml</artifactId>
            <version>${pac4jVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pac4j-oidc</artifactId>
            <version>${pac4jVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pac4j-http</artifactId>
            <version>${pac4jVersion}</version>
        </dependency>


With the logoutFilter.destroySession = true configuration, the web session should be invalidated at logout. And so should be deleted the @SessionScoped beans.
Can you turn on DEBUG logs on org.pac4j.jee.context.session.JEESessionStore and check if you see the log: Invalidate session: xxx?

yes, I can see: Invalidate session: org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpSession@15c2c03b
But if I logout and login again, the values are still in the textboxes from the session before?

Thinking about it, I'm surprised you get a log from the JEESessionStore, it should have been the specific ShiroSessionStore. In any case, I suspect that the invalidation of the web session via Shiro does not exactly invalidate the JEE HttpSession. Can you add a HttpSessionListener to see if the sessionDestroyed method is called at logout?

I´ve added a simple HttpSessionListener but it´s not called during logout. I´ve updated the code for the HttpSessionListener in my question

So I guess it'a s specific problem related to the session management in Shiro. Can you try an explicit call to session.invalidate()?

you mean: FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();if I have this, than the redirect does not work.

Yes, maybe. I'm not sure here. What you should do is duplicate the ShiroSessionStore and override the destroySession to add this extra invalidation (FacesContext or HttpSession invalidation) and check this works.

hm, not sure what you mean with "duplicate"... do you have an example etc.?

I mean copy/paste the original pac4j class with same name and package in your own project and update it. Just to make a test.

you mean just add this class: org.pac4j.jee.context.session.JEESessionStore in my project (same package etc.) and add somewhere this FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();... is there any change needed in the shiro.ini ?

Yes, no change in the shiro.ini file

hm, so I´ve added JEESessionStore class in my project and after logout it´s called function "destroySession" and also session.invalidate();
But the SessionScoped (jakarta.enterprise.context.SessionScoped) is still not destroyed from my bean.
Is the whole setup for logout correct in my post?
